# kendo ui button http post not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

In my index.cshtml page, following line of code DOES fire HttpPost so that I could get into the HttpPost tagged Index method in the controller class.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Run Calculation" />

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(TimberBeamCalculator.Models.Dimensions dim)
            {
    ..................
            }
```

But the following code for kendo ui button, does not fire the HttpPost mentioned above.

```
 @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("setting").Icon("pencil").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" }).Content("Run Calculation");
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Where is the call for the post happening? Do you not have to create a click handler for the post?

Comment: An input of type "submit" will cause the form that contains the submit button to post to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo.button does not render out as a submit button. You either need to tweak the properties of your kendo button to make it a submit button, or use jquery to do something like

```
$("#setting").click(function()
{ 
  $("#idOfYourForm").submit();
});
```

First, you should try setting the HtmlProperties of your kendo button with type of submit. If that doesn't work, go for the jquery route I mentioned.

Comment: Hi Joe, following worked for me.  @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("setting").Icon("pencil").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit" }).Content("Run Calculation");    Thanks